# Freeing up Memory from an inputstream?

Tags: java, memory-management, file-io

I'm pretty new to Java so bear with me here...

I'm using a Scanner to read an `InputStream` (which is = `Class.class.getResourceAsStream("fileName.csv")`)  .  When the file is being read, the memory starts around 44,000 and when it's done reading it gets up to 298,000.  The class basically reads the `inputStream` and puts the data into some `ArrayLists` so that I can quickly search through them.  The problem is.. I can't figure out how to get the memory usage to go down once the file is done being read.  I've tried setting the `object = null` and/or calling `System.gc()` {which apparently is only a suggestion} but neither work.  I'm using the `close()` method for both the `Scanner` and the `InputStream` and nothing has worked thus far.  Anyone have any ideas?  I guess it's possible I have no idea what I'm talking about and this is how it's supposed to be but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show more code? If you are reading and storing it into arraylists, ob it would take memory. Read it block by block in that case.

Comment: Basically it's creating an ArrayList of Customer objects which about 400,000 different customers.  I'm starting to think that maybe it's not the file that's using the memory but I'm not smart enough to really know.

Comment: Should you be worried about memory usage at this point? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil", not sure where I get this from.

Comment: How much memory is that? 298,000 bytes or 298,000 kbytes. Even if its kbytes you are talking about $2 worth of memory which is re-usable.  Don't forget that once most JVMs take memory its doesn't give it back, so reducing its usage won't give more memory to the OS.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the ArrayList of Customer objects that is taking up the memory?

Comment: How, *exactly* are you measuring the memory usage ? Generally, memory usage , as seen in task manager or something similar does go down once a process has allocated the memory. (Though this is usually not a big deal, as that memory is virtual and not physical).

Comment: @gigadot: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize and the full quote is "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" so please do not propagate the partial quote leaving out the first clause.

Comment: @JasonS That's now make sense. I have see people use the partial quote a few times on stackoverflow and I ddin't realise that it was partial.

Answer (score 2):

Once you are done using input stream you can set its reference to null, this is the only way you can ask Garbage Collector to free up the unused memory, Since we cannot force GC so there is no way to free memory explicitly.